# Exclude directories and files in zip in bash script

Tags: linux, zip, bash-scripting

I'm writing bash script that should archive some directory with python code.
I'd like to avoid archiving .pyc files, `__pycache__` directories, IPython notebooks and their checkpoints.
However, `__pycache__` subdirectories are archived anyway.

The script

```
#!/bin/bash

py_filelist='__main__.py pkg'
py_exclude='*.pyc *.ipynb \*__pycache__\* *ipynb_checkpoints*'  # <<-- Have tried many variants, nothing helps
archive_name=archive.zip

zip -rp $archive_name $py_filelist -x $py_exclude
```

On run, I'm getting the following output

```
$ bash -x script.sh

+ zip -rp archive.zip __main__.py pkg -x '*.pyc' '*.ipynb' '\*__pycache__\*' '*ipynb-checkpoints*'
adding: __main__.py (deflated 61%)
adding: pkg/ (stored 0%)
adding: pkg/file.py (deflated 62%)
adding: pkg/engine/ (stored 0%)
adding: pkg/engine/tools.py (deflated 73%)
...
adding: pkg/engine/templates/__pycache__/ (stored 0%)
...
adding: pkg/__pycache__/ (stored 0%)
```

So, only .pyc and .ipynb files have been excluded.

What is the correct way to specify exclusion pattern for `__pycache__` in script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're using shell variables is fragile, error-prone and a Bad Thing, especially in Bash where array variables are supported.

Unquoted variables undergo [word splitting and filename generation (globbing)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). In general you should always quote, except cases where you know you want word splitting and (maybe) globbing. E.g. in your code `$archive_name` should be double-quoted.

I understand you do want the content of `$py_exclude` to be split because you want to get multiple words (arguments to `zip`) from it. So you're using `$py_exclude` unquoted. The problem is with globbing.

It seems you want to get these exact strings as separate arguments: `*.pyc`, `*.ipynb`, `*__pycache__*`, `*ipynb_checkpoints*`. Each one, when unquoted or coming from an unquoted variable, triggers globbing. If there's a matching file (or files) in the current working directory, its name (their names) will be substituted in place of the respective pattern and the resulted strings will not work as intended after `zip` gets them.

I guess you had a problem with `*__pycache__*` being substituted with `__pycache__` maybe, so you added backslashes to escape the asterisks. But now these backslashes survive! Check this example:

```
$    # the current working directory is initially empty
$ variable='foo *__pycache__*'
$ printf '%s\n' "$variable"
foo *__pycache__*
$
```

OK, but you want `foo` and `*__pycache__*` to be separate arguments. You deliberately unquote the variable:

```
$    # in the same shell, same directory
$ printf '%s\n' $variable   # deliberately unquoted
foo
*__pycache__*
$
```

This is the behavior you want. But then a file may interfere:

```
$    # in the same shell, same directory
$ touch __pycache__
$ printf '%s\n' $variable   # deliberately unquoted
foo
__pycache__
$
```

This is *not* what you want, so you try to escape asterisks:

```
$    # in the same shell, same directory
$ variable='foo \*__pycache__\*'
$ printf '%s\n' $variable   # deliberately unquoted
foo
\*__pycache__\*
$
```

The backslashes survived.

Not only you have a problem with `\*__pycache__\*`. You would have problem(s) with `*.pyc` or `*.ipynb` or any other pattern if there was a matching file in the current directory.

To solve this you can disable globbing with `set -f`, drop the backslashes and still use the variable unquoted:

```
$    # in the same shell, same directory
$    # the file still exists
$ set -f
$ variable='foo *__pycache__*'
$ printf '%s\n' $variable   # deliberately unquoted
foo
*__pycache__*
$ set +f   # re-enables globbing in case we need it later
$
```

This way you can get what you want from the `$variable` and the result doesn't depend on files in the current working directory. *However* it would be hard to get `foo bar` (as a single word *with a space inside*) and `*__pycache__*` (as another word) this way. In general you want a better solution.

In Bash a better solution and ***the Right Thing*** is to use an array:

```
$    # in the same shell, same directory
$    # the file still exists
$ set +f   # globbing enabled to show it doesn't break anything
$ variable=("foo bar" '*__pycache__*')
$ printf '%s\n' "${variable[@]}"   # properly quoted
foo bar
*__pycache__*
```

This is the way to go. Use an array:

```
py_exclude=('*.pyc' '*.ipynb' '*__pycache__*' '*ipynb_checkpoints*')
```

and then get all its elements as separate words using `"${py_exclude[@]}"`.

Answer (score 1):

ipynb_checkpoints is with an _, not a -

have you tried `'*.pyc *.ipynb *__pycache__* *ipynb_checkpoints*'` ?

Comment: No. It's apparently my bug. Thank you for mentioning. However, pycache's are archived anyway. I've edited my question